# Extract text plugin specify input folder webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, build

```
 config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/styles/vendor'),
  ],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    loader: 'css-loader',
  }),
});
config.plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin('/static/styles/vendor/foundation.css'));
```

unable to get the exact folder to loop over , if I exclude the include option it creates an output file with all css of the app

Directory structure
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ExtractTextPlugin works only for files imported in your javascript. Are you sure your static content is imported in any of your js file?

Comment: correct , I just realized the same only the files in my js are getting bundled my assumption was it will extract the files I will mention in my include option.
I am switching to webpack concat plugin now.

Comment: to my surprise concat webpack plugin is supported only for webpack version  >=4 if you could suggest me a suitable plugin I will mark your answer :)
I am using next js version 5.1 that has inbuilt web pack setup that you can configure